# Python tkinter- Threading through button click

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I am displaying a sensor device's measurement values using the Tkinter GUI application. The sensor sends new data every second. I started a new thread and put the result in a Queue and process the queue to display the values on GUI. Now I am facing another problem. The sensor has two modes of operations. For simplicity, I have used a random generator in the program. Users should be able to switch the modes using two buttons. Button-1 for Mode-1, Button-2 for Mode-2.  (say the mode-1 operation is random.randrange(0,10) and mode-2 operation is random.randrange(100, 200). How do I control these two operations through Threading? if a user started a mode-1 operation, when he presses the Button-2, the mode-1 operation should stop (thread-1) and mode-2 operation (thread-2) should start. Does it mean do I need to kill thread-1? Or is there any way to control two modes in same thread? I am totally new into threading. Any suggestions, please.

```
import tkinter
import threading
import queue
import time
import random

class GuiGenerator:
    def __init__(self, master, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        # Set up the GUI
        master.geometry('800x480')
        self.output = tkinter.StringVar()
        output_label = tkinter.Label(master, textvariable= self.output)
        output_label.place(x=300, y=200)

#I haven't shown command parts in following buttons. No idea how to use it to witch modes?
        mode_1_Button  = tkinter.Button(master, text = "Mode-1")   
        mode_1_Button.place(x=600, y=300)
        mode_2_Button  = tkinter.Button(master, text = "Mode-2")
        mode_2_Button.place(x=600, y=400)

    def processQueue(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:              
                sensorOutput = self.queue.get() #Q value              
                self.output.set(sensorOutput)     #Display Q value on GUI                
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

class ClientClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

# Create the queue
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

# Set up the GUI part
        self.myGui = GuiGenerator(master, self.queue)

#How do I switch the modes of operations? do I need some flags setting through button press?

# Set up the thread to do asynchronous I/O       

        self.thread1_mode1 = threading.Thread(target=self.firstModeOperation)
        self.thread1_mode1.start()

        # Start the periodic call in the GUI to check if the queue contains
        # anything new
        self.periodicCall()

    def periodicCall(self):

        # Check every 1000 ms if there is something new in the queue.        
        self.myGui.processQueue()        
        self.master.after(1000, self.periodicCall)

    def firstModeOperation(self):        
        while True:                      #??? how do i control here through mode selection
            time.sleep(1.0)
            msg_mode_1= random.randrange(0,10)
            self.queue.put(msg_mode_1)

    def secondModeOperation(self):        
        while True:                      #??? how do i control here through mode selection
            time.sleep(1.0)
            msg_mode_2= random.randrange(100,200)
            self.queue.put(msg_mode_2)

#Operation part
root = tkinter.Tk()
client = ClientClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can define two variables for the start and end values for `randrange()`.  Then set these two variables in the button commands.  So only one thread is enough.

Comment: @acw1668 As I mentioned, I used the random generator in the program just simplify here. Actual modes of operations contain some calculations. So two modes are entirely different.

Comment: So how do you switch the sensor mode actually? By a switch on the senor or sending command to it?

Comment: Or define a variable holding the sensor mode.  In the while loop of the thread task, check the sensor mode and do corresponding operations accordingly.

Comment: only the calculation part is different. Sensor values are always same. But the calculation before displaying the values are different. And I am gonna save values in two different text files based on the mode of selection.